# access graph api in multiple pages in a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am unable to access Graph Api in other pages other than the initial page load on my facebook app.

Any ways I can access the Access Token in other pages on my app?
Cause the signed_request is available only at the index page

Anyone can help with it?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses a $_SESSION to store all crucial information including Userid, Accesstoken etc.. Your index page obviously has a

```
require 'facebook.php';
```

Make sure you add the same line at the top of the next page. Immediately after that add a

```
start_session();
```

Now you can perform a

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

and you will be able to see all important info that facebook has stored and you can use them. (Provided user is still logged in and token has not expired).